# Why does Xcode keep recompiling my untouched project?

Tags: xcode, xcode4

I have an Xcode 4 workspace with several projects. Everything builds perfectly and works as expected, only Xcode recompiles files too often. If I hit the Build button, wait for the compilation to succeed and then hit the button again, shouldn’t that be essentialy a no-op, since no files have changed? Because my Xcode recompiles a big part of the project again. Even when I build and then immediately hit the Play button, I have to stare at the building process again. Is that neccessary, is it expected behaviour?

Comment: I too am having the exact same issue - I'd love it if anyone could give some insight.

Comment: I have the same issue but it also happens in Xcode 5.

Comment: there could be many contributing factors. can you be more specific? any external build systems? any shell scripts? are you changing anything? not just code but settings can cause recompiles.

Comment: My apologies. Cocoapods is the new player in town. http://cocoapods.org/ Our project depends on cocoapods managing our dependencies. So, yes settings. No scripts. This is just running it on the desktop. What settings should I be looking at?

Comment: Is this just with 1 project or all projects? If you open the project on another Mac does it still happen?

Comment: Yes, if I open the project on another mac it happens.

Comment: It does not happen with the same project before cocoapods was installed and used.

Comment: As is the way with cocoapods, there are two targets. One says Pods and the other is the App.

Comment: Could it be a circular dependency?

Comment: Are you referring to our project depending on the Pods scheme and it depending on our project, @WarrenP ?

Comment: Perhaps, a project level dependency or an unintentional circular link of another sort, perhaps involving symlinks?

Answer (score 4):

Shot in the dark, but do you have external xcode projects linked? XCode may be recompiling because it doesn't know the state of those projects.

Either way, you can always Run Without Building ^⌘R (control + command + r)

Comment: Still looking for the cause though. I change one line of code and it recompiles the whole thing. see details above.

Comment: Neither answer helped our particular situation. However, this one provided a helpful tip which I can use. So, I awarded the 50 points here since time has run out. Enjoy and thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Are you executing custom scripts that change files before compilation? This will result that xcode will recompile all touched files even though maybe nothing changed.
You can turn this off by enabling a checkmark in the run script build phase. This will execute the script only on installation of the app.

The image below shows the actual checkmark.

[image: Run script image]

Comment: No, we are not. However, that is an insightful answer! It may help someone else in the future.